# error in barplot R

Tags: r, bar-chart

i use this code to reprsent my data in barplot.

```
m<-matrix(c(0.3266765,0.02333991,0.02654504,0.0243261,0.5162414,
            0.09647816,0.4568512,0.452532,0.3976825,0.006431235,
            0.007935491,0.004401323),ncol=4,byrow=TRUE)
colnames(m)<-c("HPI","JAC","SAL","HDI")
rownames(m)<-c("Zackary Karaté Club","American College Football","Political Blogs")
m<-as.table(m)
colors<-rainbow(4)
barplot(t(m), beside= TRUE, legend.text=colnames(m), 
        col=colors, ylab="Modularity", ylim=c(0,1))
```

But, my problem is in the result, i will have three barplot, i have the name in the first and third, which is the rownames of the table ,but in the second i dont' have it. can anyone helps me?? thanks

you can see the problem once you execute the code. i can't upload the image.

Comment: I don't get it. I see three names when I [plot that](http://imgur.com/oJBR3WI)

Comment: You need to resize your window to make it bigger. The 2nd name is drop if there isn't enough room for it.

Comment: If you are using RStudio, click on "Zoom" in the "Plots" widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another option to the previous answers. it's to add the `cex.names` to the `barplot` command to define the size of the text. the problem was the size of the text which was big.

```
barplot(t(m), beside= TRUE, legend.text=colnames(m), col=colors, ylab="Modularity", ylim=c(0,1), cex.names=0.75)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you resize the plot window large enough, the labels should appear.

- Use `dev.size()` to get the size of your plot window.
- `x11(width=10,height=10)` will start a window of the specified size (for X window server).

Otherwise, you may want to consider using custom labels. See `xaxt` option in `plot` and the `axis` commands.